# Message from server to client in Alert window

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I have this

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    char[] charArray = reverse(request.getParameter("field").toCharArray());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

}

public char[] reverse(char[] array){
    int id = 0;
    char[] newArr = new char[array.length];
    for(int i=array.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        newArr[id] = array[i];
        id++;
    }
    return newArr;      
}
```

How can i hand off charArray to the main WebPage in AlertWindow?
Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSP than you can use following code:

```
request.setAttribute(xyz,reverse(abc).toString);
```

above code will set attribute in request object then do below in your JSP:

```
document.ready(){
    alert(<%out.write(request.getAttribute(xyz))%>);
}
```

Comment: Can u explain it to me, like for a dummy? Cant deal it

Comment: Firstly if you are using JSP than do as follow:  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {
      char[] charArray =   reverse(request.getParameter("field").toCharArray());
     request.setAttribute(charArray);  than in your jsp page you can retrive that attribute from request and print that value between alert using scriptlet.

Comment: It returns Null. Did i understand right, that "xyz" absolutely random variable name?

Comment: Yes you are right, Its random variable name. after setting variable in request you need to do request.getRequestDispatcher("yourPage.jsp").forward(request, response); if you are using request.sendRedirect() than it won't work in that case use session instead of request.

Comment: Done it. But still is null Do u have TeamViewer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Ajax call to your servlet like below example....
In your jsp write below javascript

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function callServelet(){  
          $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "Controler(your servelet name)?field=("your field to process")",
            success : function(responseText) {
            alert(responseText);
            }
          });  
        }   
    </script>
```

on your servlet

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    char[] charArray = reverse(request.getParameter("field").toCharArray());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(charArray);
 }
```